# Show that a problem belongs to NP

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, reductions

A logistics company has two trucks and has to deliver some packages to some addresses. The manager has to create a plan for every driver.

Input Data: A set of V locations, an array d[v,u] for every pair of locations u,v belongs to V. The distance (integer) is also stored between the locations. A starting point and an integer k.

Are there two circles that begin from the starting point so that every location (v belongs to V) that belongs to at least one of the circles and every circle has a maximum length of k?

I have to form this problem in a language and that belongs to NP class. I also have to show if is NP-Complete by reduction to a known NP-complete language. 
Any ideas to the above questions?

Comment: Hello! We discourage posts that simply state a problem out of context, and expect the community to solve it. Assuming you tried to solve it yourself and got stuck, it may be helpful if you wrote your thoughts and what you could not figure out. It will definitely draw more answers to your post. You may also want to check out [these hints](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98), or use the search engine of this site to find similar questions that were already answered.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but the point of this kind of exercise is to get you used to working things out for yourself. Membership in **NP** is usually easiest to demonstrate by showing that you can verify a proposed solution deterministically in polynomial time; **NP**-hardness is usually easiest to show by reducing a similar-sounding problem to it. I can think of a very famous **NP**-complete problem that's essentially the one-truck version of your problem.

Comment: Also, I don't think you are talking about a _circle_. Do you mean a _cycle_ or a _tour_?

Comment: It is a cycle indeed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is just a (homework?) problem dump.

Answer (score 0):

Take an instance of “Hamiltonian circle”. Then construct an instance of your problem where one truck can just visit one point, and the other needs to solve the Hamiltonian Circle problem.

It happens quie often when you have a more complicated problem, that you can solve an instance of a simpler NP-complete problem by constructing an instance of the more complicated problem so that a solution forces a solution of the simpler problem.